Schengen visa photo missing color: Will this be a problem with airline/ immigration?
I just had gotten Schengen visa for Spain. Problem is the printer missed the skin color on the forehead & neck. The rest of the visa info is printed correctly. Will this be a problem with airline/ immigration ?

There should not be any problem, as this is normal problem caused due printer or part of forehead & neck is interpreted as background. As long as the details are clearly visible on the visa, that should be not be any problem.

Spanish border police will probably pull up your visa details on their computer and see that it's all there anyway
